# Error con la ubicación del archivo

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente código:

```py
def text_with_pattern(arg, archivo):
    try:
        archivo = open(archivo,'r')
        tests = [linea.rstrip('\n').split(':') for linea in archivo]
        for test in tests:
            frase = arg
            for idx in range(len(test)):
                frase = frase.replace(str(idx), test[idx])

            print(frase)
    except IOError:
        print("No se ha encontrado el archivo.")
    finally:
        archivo.close()

text_with_pattern("1 me dijo que 0 vendría con 2",
                  "D:\entornoServidor\classes\exercises/filename.txt")
```

A la hora de cambiar la ruta de **absoluta** (`D:\entornoServidor\classes\exercises/filename.txt`) al **nombre del archivo** (`filename.txt`) me da el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\entornoServidor\classes\exercises\Practica_01.py", line 16, in <module>
    text_with_pattern("1 me dijo que 0 vendría con 2","filename.txt")
  File "D:\entornoServidor\classes\exercises\Practica_01.py", line 14, in text_with_pattern
    archivo.close()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'close'
```

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estás usando el nombre `archivo` para dos cosas:

1. argumento `archivo` para el nombre del fichero (tipo `str`)
2. referencia al fichero abierto con `open()` (tipo `file`)

La variable `archivo` se machaca con la referencia al fichero abierto con `open()`. Si da error la apertura, mantendrá su valor como nombre del fichero. De ahí el error cuando intenta cerrarlo con `archivo.close()`.

La cláusula `finally` se ejecuta siempre, haya o no error. Para limpiar ficheros abiertos, lo que tendrías que usar es la cláusula `else` que sólo se ejecuta cuando no se produce ningún error:

```py
try:
    archivo = open(archivo,'r')
    ...

except IOError:
    print("No se ha encontrado el archivo.")
else:
    archivo.close()
```

Comment: Correcto muchas gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido @AntonioOrtegaChinchilla ! Si la respuesta de Chema te ha servido la mejor forma de agradecer es marcar la respuesta, como "respuesta correcta" y por qué no, votarla positiva, eso no solo agradece su ayuda si no que permite que la pregunta perduré en el tiempo y ayude a más personas en el futuro. Te recomiendo leer Te recomiendo leer [Vota pronto, vota con frecuencia](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2209/vota-pronto-vota-con-frecuencia)